# How do i check if an email exist in Firebase using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, authentication

```
// Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyA_kaqHtpvjFeagx0BYKdSCeQVCDvG5ESM",
    authDomain: "pilot-860c1.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://pilot-860c1.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "pilot-860c1",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "897069842460"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);

  // references message collections

  var messageRef = firebase.database().ref("messages");

window.onload = form;

// Legg til en addEventListener som ser etter en submit, og kall funksjonen submitForm
  function form(){
    document.getElementById("signupform").addEventListener("submit", submitForm);
  }


  function submitForm(e){

    e.preventDefault();


    // hent values
    var fname = getInputValues("fname");
    var lname = getInputValues("lname");
    var email = getInputValues("email");
    var phone = getInputValues("phone");
    var pass = getInputValues("p1");


    // save form and info
    saveForm(fname, lname, email, phone, pass);

    // show alert if sent
    document.getElementById("formRegistered").style.display = "block";


    // hide alert after 3 sec and hide formRegistered span
    setTimeout(function(){
      document.getElementById('formRegistered').style.display = "none";
    }, 3000);

    // reset form after
    document.getElementById("signupform").reset();

  }

  function getInputValues(id){
    return document.getElementById(id).value;

  }
// Save form like this
  function saveForm(fname, lname, email, phone, pass){
    var newMessageRef = messageRef.push();
    newMessageRef.set({
      name: fname,
      lastname: lname,
      email: email,
      phone: phone,
      pw: pass
    });
  }
```

So this is my code, I´ve tried adding if statements but i can´t seem to access my firebase to check if that email exists, I want to basically tell the user the email is already registered if its exisiting in my firebase. I've looked at the documentation too but i dont get it

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Firebase Auth for signing up and authenticating your users, instead of writing them to the DB, because basically to write into the database you will need users, and if you are planning to keep the db open to writes, then its probably a bad idea.

[Firebase Auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start)

Next step using firebase auth you can check if the user exists by using the following method, which returns a non empty List if the user exists/has been signed up

[fetch Providers for email](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#fetchProvidersForEmail)